# Set current date time in datetime field using JSLINK CSR

Tags: sharepoint-online, jslink, client-side-rendering

Using CSR I am able to set value of date field, but for **time** field it's not working.
following code works for date field without time:

```
ctx.CurrentFieldValue = "01/01/2015";
return SPFieldDateTime_Edit(ctx);
```

but for datetime field with "Date & Time" I do not know in which format I should pass the date time value:

I think there I am passing time value in a wrong format
01/01/2015 01 AM 05 - not working
01/01/2015 10PM 05 - not working

```
ctx.CurrentFieldValue = "01/01/2015 01 AM 05";
return SPFieldDateTime_Edit(ctx);
```

what is the correct format?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you had the 24h Time Format not 12h Time Format then correct string format will be: "01/01/2015 15:35"

The best way to now how format you must use, its check how SharePoint save those value. You can do this use the code:

```
var TestJSLinkRendering= TestJSLinkRendering || {};    
TestJSLinkRendering.CustomizeFieldRendering = function () {
        var ctx = {};
        ctx.Templates = {};
        ctx.Templates.Fields = {
            'Internal Name Date Time Field':{
                'EditForm': TestJSLinkRendering.TEST
            }
        };
        SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(ctx);
    };

    TestJSLinkRendering.TEST = function(ctx){
        console.log(ctx.CurrentFieldValue);
        var fieldType = ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.FieldType;
       var defaultTemplates = SPClientTemplates._defaultTemplates.Fields.default.all.all;
       return defaultTemplates[fieldType]["EditForm"](ctx);
    }

    TestJSLinkRendering.CustomizeFieldRendering();
```

And use the same format.